# Doubts Thread | Node.JS comparation

Tags: multithreading

I have been reading a lot about Node.JS and i'm with a doubt.
NodeJS is single thread but, let's say for example, IIS it isn't also single thread?
If my server has a CPU with one core shouldn't be single thread also? I read that the number of threads are relative to the number of CPU cores.

I ask that because I also read that in IIS we have one thread by connection. Is it possible?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general application, the number of threads is not bound by the number of cores.  IIS may have an arbitrary number of threads on a single core CPU.

Javascript, Flash, and most other web applications are single threaded by the design of the Web Browser.  This does not extend to the server though.